# In a pm2-daemonized nodejs script listening for MQTT messages, how to also listen for a specific keystroke?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a nodejs script daemonized with pm2 which listens for MQTT messages as part of an IOT setup. Everything is working fine.

But I'd also like this nodejs script to constantly listen for a specific single keystroke and perform an operation when it hears it.

I've googled (obviously) but all the results I get are for typical "type x now" user prompts for keystrokes which seems (?) like a different animal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a full solution for you, but could [keypress](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress) be something you're looking for? Although since your script is daemonized with pm2, i'm not sure if it'll properly capture stdin.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've been researching and getting advice from people and it sounds pretty difficult. Daemons (pm2 or otherwise) aren't really set up to receive stdin. And the OS has an idea of focus as to where keystrokes should go. Not an easy solution, for sure.

Comment: i was able to receive keypresses without having the window in focus with [iohook](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook), but i have not tried putting it behind pm2. good luck!

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned pm2 or node. This issue is just about getting keyboard input to a specific process. Found a pretty good answer on superuser which leverages lirc and its associated packages (lirc is for infra red remote controls, usually). I'm going through it now.